# How to have multiple sitemap classes in a single django app?

Tags: django, sitemap

I have my_app in django 'my_project'.
I have two models in my_app

```
class Author(model):
    name = CharField(...)
    created_at = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url()
        kwargs = {'author_pk': self.pk, }
        return reverse('author', kwargs=kwargs)


class Post(model):
    title = CharField(...)
    author = ForeignKey(Author, ...)
    created_at = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url()
        kwargs = {'author_pk': slef.author.pk, 'post_pk': self.pk, }
        return reverse('author', kwargs=kwargs)
```

I have a file name sitemap in my_app folder as below:

```
class AuthorSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "monthly"
    priority = 0.9

    def items(self):
        return Author.objects.all()

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.updated_at


class PostSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "monthly"
    priority = 0.9

    def items(self):
        return Post.objects.all()

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.updated_at
```

in my_project folder in urls file I have this:

```
sitemaps = {
    'my_app': PartnerSitemap, 'my_app': PartnerBlogPostSitemap,
}

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    ...
    path('sitemap.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),

]
```

As you see, I have a dictionary within which I have two items having the same key. I changed it as below. It still did not work:

```
sitemaps = {
    'my_app': [PartnerSitemap, PartnerBlogPostSitemap, ]
}
```

How should I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

It worked this way:

```
sitemaps = {
    'my_app1': AuthorSitemap
    'my_app2', PostSitemap, 
}
```

It seems that the app name is not important. The sitemap dictionary is used just for its key values. It is written to pass the key values only. I could write it as below:

```
sitemaps = {
    'my_app_author': AuthorSitemap
    'my_app_post', PostSitemap, 
}
```